# Query regarding static class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Hi all I just wanted to know whether a static class which inherits another class, can have access to the parent classe's non static members or not? 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A `static` class cannot inherit or implement any class or interface.

The point of inheriting or implementing a class or interface is to allow instances of your class to be used as the base type.
Since static classes cannot have instances, there's no point.

Answer (score 0):

How should that work? A static class cannot be instantiated and therefor it will never have access to any non static members.

Comment: Furthermore, static class can't inherit or be inherited

Answer (score 0):

> A static class is basically the same
>   as a non-static class, but there is
>   one difference: a static class cannot
>   be instantiated. In other words, you
>   cannot use the new keyword to create a
>   variable of the class type

You can view more information about [static classes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`static class` cannot inherited .

I think you can go with the same concept with `SingleTon` class and you can inherit the same.

Answer (score 0):

A static class can't inherit from any classes or implement any interfaces.

A static class does implicitly inherit from `Object`, though. But since it's (also implicitly) abstract you can never have any instances of it, and so can never call any instance methods in `Object`. Also, it's (implicitly) sealed, and as such cannot have subclasses that would be instantiatable. As a corollary to these characteristics, it can't be used to type any variables, fields or parameters; and it can't be used as a type parameter (if these were possible, `null` would be the only valid value for such references).

Given all this, a static class [does not look like a class at all](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-static-classes-are-not-real-classes.html), and I think would be better represented as a module.